# Move constructor trigger unexpectedly by template constructor (std::function and mini case)

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constructor, rvalue-reference

In code below, why F's move ctor is invoked?

I ran into this case when I tried to wrap std::function, and surprised to find that my inner functor was moved twice during construction.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct F {
    F() { cout << "F()" << endl; }
    F(const F &) { cout << "F(const F &)" << endl; }
    F(F &&) {
        cout << "F(F &&)" << endl;
    }

    void operator()() { cout << "F::()()" << endl;}
};

struct I {
#if 0
    // F's move ctor not invoked
    I(F &&) { }
#else
    // F's move ctor invoked, why?
    template<typename FT, typename = void>
    I(FT) { } // Simulate std::function ctor prototype
#endif
};

struct FF {
    FF(F &&f) : _impl(std::move(f)) {} // [line1] Debugger show source here
    I _impl;
};

int main() {
    FF ff = F();
    (void)ff;
    cout << "----" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

(using g++ 4.8.x-5.3.x)

gdb shows that the unexpected move ctor called by [line1], but I cannot comprehend it.
Could anyone explain it to me?

Besides, in my real case (replace class I by std::function), is there any way to construct wrapper class FF without the inner functor F moved twice?

Comment: That's the place of `std::forward` and forwarding reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your templated version of the `I` constructor takes its parameter by value instead of by rvalue reference. The by-value parameter is constructed by the invocation of the move constructor that you're wondering about.

You need a 'universal reference' style constructor instead, which declares its parameter as an rvalue reference. This is the idiom that allows perfect forwarding as used by `std::function` and other constructs.

So change:

```
template<typename FT, typename = void>
I(FT) { } // Simulate std::function ctor prototype
```

To:

```
template<typename FT, typename = void>
I(FT&&) { } // Simulate std::function ctor prototype
```

To elaborate somewhat: you might have thought that by simply providing a value that has an rvalue reference type in your invocation, the compiler would instantiate the type `FT` to be an rvalue reference, i.e. `F&&`. However, that is not how template deduction works in this situation: the compiler will only deduce the 'decayed' type, i.e. `F` in this case. If you want the parameter to be a reference you must explicitly specify a reference type as your parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the expalantion. But then the std::function problem is unfixable? std::function ctor is in the form of function(_Functor __f)

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'problem'. The `std::function` ctor that you refer to takes its functor parameter by value, which means some ctor of `F` (either copy or move)  _must_ run when said `std::function` ctor is invoked. Your wrapper does not need to add another ctor call on top of this. What are you concerned about exactly?

Comment: 1. Let "using I = std::function<void>;", then "FF ff = F();" will trigger F(F&&) twice. 2. "std::function<void> sf = F();" trigger F(F&&) only once. In case of 1, not sure it is g++ that is unable to ellide the ctor, or the spec disallow such kind of optimization to happen.

Comment: It is the implementation of the `std::function` constructor here that is causing the 2nd move. Internally, `std::function` actually moves its parameter (which it has by value remember) into an internal storage area.  The only reason you don't see 2 moves in your direct `std::function` construction is because you're constructing its parameter in-place to start with, so its by-value param is constructed directly rather than moved into. To demonstrate my point, you will also see 2 moves if you do this: `auto f = F(); std::function<void()> func = std::move(f);`

Comment: The whole point of move semantics is that move construction is supposed to be cheap: is it not the case with your classes?